# conflict for both use @transantional and tx:advice

Tags: spring, transactions

I have some questions on both use `@Transactional` annotation and xml config `tx:advice` in the same project.

1. If my class is inside the `tx:advice`'s pointcut, and i set the annotation `@Transactional` on the class,which one would become effective? From my simple test,the `tx:advice` effectived? why?
2. If the first class is not within the `tx:advice`'s pointcut and i set the `@Transactional`, then I invoke a method within the `tx:advice`'s pointcut,would it be conflicted?For I am seem to get the exception: `[Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@14e9851] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@4dd1b] bound to thread]`

Comment: It shouldn't matter, unless you are using multiple transaction managers then it might break. But you haven't shown any code / configuration so that is hard to see.

Comment: @M. Deinum,Thanks for your formatter and answer...In order to complete my work,I change my code to fit the tx:advice configuration. So I didn't put my code..Your answer remind me to check the configuration and I find the problem, for is don't set the annotation-driver for the transaction manager that tx:advice used(the project is setup by my teammate, so i ignored it).  Thanks very much.